# Datafx Link Action (Not working)

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

Trying to understand why my datafx flow is not working.  I have 2 class `WIPController.class(Master)` and `DeliverableEditFXMLController.class(Detail)`
Below is how I create the flow

```
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        DefaultFlowContainer flowContainer = new DefaultFlowContainer(pane);
        Flow flow = new Flow(WIPController.class)
                .withLink(WIPController.class, "bEditAction", DeliverableEditFXMLController.class)
                .withLink(DeliverableEditFXMLController.class, "bSaveAction", WIPController.class)
                ;                
        flow.createHandler().start(flowContainer);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

Below is bare WIPController.class

```
@FXMLController(value="fxml/WIP.fxml")
public class WIPController  {

    @FXMLViewFlowContext
    private ViewFlowContext context;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableView<CaseDeliverable> ttblWIP;

    @FXML
    @LinkAction(DeliverableEditFXMLController.class)
    private Button bTestAction;     

    @FXML
    @ActionTrigger("bEditAction")
    private Button bEdit; }
```

`bEdit` button is meant to take you to (`Details`) controller.  View shows but will I click button nothing happens
I added `bTestAction` see if I could get it to happen via `linkaction` annotation but nothing happens.

```
@FXMLController("fxml/DeliverableEditFXML.fxml")
public class DeliverableEditFXMLController  {

    @FXMLViewFlowContext
    private ViewFlowContext context;    

    @FXML
    @ActionTrigger("bSaveAction")
    private Button bSave;
}
```

Above is details controller as you can see trying to get `bSave` button take back to Master View.

At the moment `bEdit` button does not event take me to `Detail` view.  If anyone can help me understand what wrong with would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with code but seems like jar was using for datafx was broken.
[Download all jar for datafx from Mavern repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.datafx)